# Load SQL tables in HTML page

Tags: html, sql

EDIT: Updated code, still not working

I'm trying to get tables to be displayed on html through a button click, unless it is possible to automatically load up tables on page initiation.

I keep running into an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() on Line 15.

I am using a .php script

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include ("ConnDetails.php");
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Tracks");
if ($result !== false) {
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Tracks<th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Tracks'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "You have encountered an error";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: pay attention to that in the end you need to use `</table>` instead of `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Tracks'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<table>";
} else {
echo "You have encountered an error";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Tried this before mate still getting same error but for fetch_assoc instead of array. Cheers though

Comment: I think it's your SQL calling problem.  `$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Tracks");`  and `$result = $conn->query($sql);` use it may be works.